# how to find last and second last record in separate column all customers in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, db2-400

I have single table in which have column like customer no, recharge mrp , date

how to find last and second last recharge in separate column for all customers in sql

I have recharge mrp column i want customer wise last and second last recharge in separate column
Please help me.

Comment: Please post any code you have tried.

Comment: Why is this tagged Oracle and db2? Which database are you using?

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags, and include sample data, an example of the results you expect based on the sample data you've posted, and the query you've tried. Without that it's going to be rather difficult to guess at what you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then mrp end) as last_mrp,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then mrp end) as second_to_last_mrp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by customer
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @gordon will give you one row for customer with his last and second last recharge.

If you want last and second last recharge of the customer for each recharge then you can use following query:

```
select customer, date, mrp
lag(mrp,1) over (partition by customer order by date) as last_mrp,
lag(mrp,2) over (partition by customer order by date) as second_last_mrp
from t
```

Cheers!!